# supabase suscription configuration does not work

Tags: reactjs, supabase

I am trying to make the new object added to the events table appear on the console when I create an event, using `supabase realtime`. I have the configuration in supabase activated for realtime and the strangest thing is that yesterday the same script returned the payload in the console.The subscription is listening to the events table.

```
  const[events, setEvents] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getUser();
    const subscription = supabase
    .from('events')
    .on('*', (payload) => {
      console.log(payload)
    })
    .subscribe();
    return() => {
      supabase.removeSubscription(subscription)
    }
  }, []);
```

Will I have the supabase subscription misconfigured?

Comment: The code looks great, and given that it was working a day ago, there might be something wrong on the server side of things. If you could send a message to support@supabase.io with your project reference, we should be able to take a look at your project and get back to you.

Comment: Hi @dshukertjr I did it, I sent them and email. Thanks